# Angular User Data Ng-Class

Tags: angularjs, global

I'm trying to set a global object with user data (id, name, etc) and use it in a template to color comments. Like if the user is logged in, it highlights their comments.

I've tried this:

```
app.factory('UserService', function() {
   return {
       name : 'Johnny Williams',
       id : 2
   };
});
```

then I set the comment name to UserService.name and that works. BUT What I wan't to do is this:

```
var setcommentClass = function(comment) {
if (comment.name === UserService.name) {comment.type = 'user'}
else {comment.type = 'client'}
};
```

Then in the template use this:

```
ng-class="{user: comment.type == 'user' }
```

This doesn't work. Why is that? There's got to be a more eloquent way to do this. I don't want to store "comment.type" in the database because it is useless information. I've tried using:

```
ng-class="{user: comment.name == UserService.name }
```

but that didn't work either. I feel like that would be the easiest way. What is the protocol on using global information not tied to a scope and using it in the template itself? While also keeping user data secure.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to refer the service within html document, you'll have to assign it to `$scope`.
You can try:

```
$scope.UserService = UserService;
```

in your controller.